# "Cannot access a disposed object" when checking for IsDisposed and Disposing

Tags: c#, winforms, objectdisposedexception

When the application receives a call from the service, it opens a form for each call. The user must make his input in each window and the close it. In order to smooth the user's work I am trying to reactivate the window the user was working on when the next one is being shown.

The method for doing this is below:

```
private void ActivatePreviousActiveForm() {

    if (_activeWhenOpen != null && _activeWhenOpen.InvokeRequired) {
         if (!_activeWhenOpen.Disposing || !_activeWhenOpen.IsDisposed)
              _activeWhenOpen.Invoke((MethodInvoker)ActivatePreviousActiveForm);
    } else
         if (_activeWhenOpen != null && !(_activeWhenOpen is FrmRuntimeError))
             _activeWhenOpen.Activate();
}
```

Sometime it throws ""Cannot access a disposed object" when reaching the line

```
if (!_activeWhenOpen.Disposing || !_activeWhenOpen.IsDisposed)
```

Does anyone know why this would happen?

Comment: A quick guess would be, you should try to inverse the condition. Probably that if an object is fully disposed, Disposing would bug out.

Comment: Probably because the CLR garbage collector has already cleaned up the disposed object so it no longer actually exists.

Comment: @Liam: Disposing an object doesn't make it collected by the GC, since it's still referenced in the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to invert the *if* condition:

This line

`if (!_activeWhenOpen.Disposing || !_activeWhenOpen.IsDisposed)`

has to become

`if (!_activeWhenOpen.IsDisposed || !_activeWhenOpen.Disposing)`

That is because the condition are checked in the order they are written, so your code may call `Disposing` on an object that is alredy disposed, raising your error.

EDIT:

I also think that you should change the **||** to a **&&** , because if your window is not Disposed but is in Disposing status, you may have an error.

Comment: I guess I should have create the answer instead of putting it in a comment. :D

Comment: whops! I didn't see the comment when i clicked on the answer button! Sorry!

Comment: @il_gury: don't be sorry, I just wasn't fully sure

Comment: @il_guru makes perfect sense... should have seen that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access a disposed object. Why is it disposed? When the user closes the form, the default behavior of closing is to dispose it. In order to prevent that, you'll have to override the Close method so it just hides the form instead of dispose it. Like this:

```
// Use this event handler for the FormClosing event.
private void YourFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  this.Hide();
  e.Cancel = true; // this will cancel the close event.
}
```

Regards.

Comment: The form is not automatically disposed if it is shown with the ShowDialog method, only if it is shown with the Show method.